# Can't locate element by xpath in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, nosuchelementexception

I am learning python and selenium right now by making a small script that posts birthday comments to my facebook friends. I am able to successfully login and navigate to the "friends' birthday" modal, but then I am unable to comment in the textbox.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="u_i_6"]"}
```

I haven't had any issues finding other page elements via XPath so I am not sure what is causing the issue. I also tried finding the textbox to comment via classname, but had the same result. Can anyone offer some thoughts?

[image]

EDIT: forgot to paste code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import config
# fetch facebook password from separate file in the same directory
pw = config.secret['pw']
keyboard = Controller()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

# navigate to facebook url
driver.get('https://facebook.com')

# input email address
email_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
email_input.send_keys(<omitted>)
# input pw
password_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]')
password_input.send_keys(pw)
# click login button element
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_b"]')
login_button.click()

home_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_c"]/a')
# wait 8 seconds for browser popup before pressing esc to get out
time.sleep(8)
keyboard.press(Key.esc)

# check if there are any birthdays today
birthday_section = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="home_birthdays"]/div/div/div/div/a/div/div/span/span[1]')
birthday_section.click()

first_comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_i_6"]')
first_comment.send_keys('happy birthday!')
# click post button to post comment

# close browser window after actions are complete
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

Comment: use webdriverwait or else check presence of iframe to locate your element

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer without the code, but here are a couple of ideas:

1. Make sure you are using some sort of [Selenium wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), implicit or explicit, so your code does not search for an element before this element appears on the page. You can add this code after `driver.get()` for implicit wait:

```py
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

2. Also, it looks like IDs are dynamic on that page, I get a different one on my FB page. Try using this `xpath` to find the textarea:

```
"//form[contains(@action, 'birthday')]//textarea"
```

Hope this is helpful, good luck!